# Jquery UI select

Tags: php, jquery, user-interface, e-commerce

I am new to jquery UI

I wanted to perform some validation using jquery ui select.

I have two select boxes like

COLOR

RED   GREEN   BLUE   YELLOW

SIZE

L S XL XXL

on selecting the color, if there is any size not available I add "na" class to the size selectee

and I have use cancel -- option to disable the selection with class ".na"

All I need is to generate an error message when user clicks on the na class

or some sort of cancel callback....

Also I need to know how to use start:function(event,ui) to get to know the current element being selected...

Thanks all in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*All I need is to generate an error message when user clicks on the na class*

```
$(document).on('click','.na',function(){
  console.log("Error message generated");
});
```

*Also I need to know how to use start:function(event,ui)*

use `selecting( event, ui )`

`ui.selecting`

> The current selectable item being selected